# ChartJS line chart drag and zoom

Tags: javascript, python, django, chart.js, linechart

Is it possible to add drag and zoom on ChartJS? I would like to do something similar like [here](https://jsfiddle.net/4w626v2s/2/).

Here is how I draw my line chart:

```
<canvas class="square_margin_less" id="myChart" width="100" height="30" > </canvas>
<script>
new Chart(document.getElementById("myChart").getContext('2d'),
{
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        labels: {{ data.labels|safe }},
        datasets:
        [{
            label: 'x',
            data: {{ data.x }},
            borderColor: 'rgba(233,105,118,1)',
        },
        {
            label: 'y',
            data: {{ data.y }},
            borderColor: 'rgba(96,143,239,1)'
        },
        {
            label: 'z',
            data: {{ data.z }},
            borderColor: 'rgba(144,247,136,1)'
        }]
    },
});
</script>
```

There is some way of personalizing this?

Comment: To answer your question, yes, it is possible. You could do it yourself, or check out this plugin that a simple google search turned up. https://github.com/chartjs/chartjs-plugin-zoom

Answer (score 3):

I didn't find "drag and zoom" functionality for Chart.js as well as simple example with "pan and zoom" version so I've decided to implement demo version own my own.

List of external scripts is very important: `hammer-js`, then `Chart.bundle.js` and `chartjs-plugin-zoom.js`.

```js
const config = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: [new Date('2019-08-20'), new Date('2019-08-25'), new Date('2019-08-30')],
    datasets: [{
      label: 'Line',
      data: [2, 5, 3],
      borderColor: '#D4213D',
      fill: false,
    }, ],
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        type: 'time',
      }, ],
    },
    pan: {
      enabled: true,
      mode: 'xy',
    },
    zoom: {
      enabled: true,
      mode: 'xy', // or 'x' for "drag" version
    },
  },
};

window.onload = function() {
  new Chart(document.getElementById('chart'), config);
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/hammer.js/2.0.8/hammer.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.8.0/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chartjs-plugin-zoom/0.6.6/chartjs-plugin-zoom.js"></script>
<html>
<body>
  <div style="width:380px;">
    <canvas id="chart"></canvas>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

If someone is interesting in other libraries, I found one interesting solution on Vicotry website with "brush and zoom" functionality for line charts: https://formidable.com/open-source/victory/guides/brush-and-zoom/.

**EDIT:** In the "drag" version you will have to use for zoom:

```
drag: {
   borderColor: 'hsl(35, 100%, 60%)',
   borderWidth: '3',
   backgroundColor: 'hsl(35, 100%, 60%)',
},
```